# Python debugging simple script

Tags: python

So as part of a script I'm writing to play tic tac toe, I have a 'win checker' which takes as its input:

1. a list of numbers which denote positions
2. who started the game

It's not really important for the problem I'm having, but I thought some background might help. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
import random
import pdb
def win_checker(position_list, turn2):
    win_list1 = []
    win_list2 = []
    for bud in xrange(len(position_list)):
        if bud % 2 == 0:
            win_list1.append(position_list[bud])
            print win_list1
            if 1 and 2 and 3 in win_list1:
                return True
            if 4 and 5 and 6 in win_list1:
                return True
            if 7 and 8 and 9 in win_list1:
                return True
            if 1 and 4 and 7 in win_list1:
                return True
            if 2 and 5 and 8 in win_list1:
                return True
            if 3 and 6 and 9 in win_list1:  
                return True
            if 1 and 5 and 9 in win_list1:
                return True
            if 3 and 5 and 7 in win_list1:               
                return True
        elif bud % 1 == 0:
            win_list2.append(position_list[bud])
            print win_list2

            if 1 and 2 and 3 in win_list2:
                return True
            if 4 and 5 and 6 in win_list2:
                return True
            if 7 and 8 and 9 in win_list2:
                return True
            if 1 and 4 and 7 in win_list2:
                return True
            if 2 and 5 and 8 in win_list2:
                return True
            if 3 and 6 and 9 in win_list2:
                return True
            if 1 and 5 and 9 in win_list2:
                return True
            if 3 and 5 and 7 in win_list2:
                return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then when I try the script for a certain position:

```
win_checker([5,1,3,2], 1)
[5]
[1]
[5, 3]
Out[57]: True
```

I don't understand why the output is True, if someone could explain what I'm missing that would be very helpful to me

Comment: Please see the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- a good question around code will contain a **minimal**, complete, verifiable example -- meaning the smallest possible amount of code that will produce the same problem. In this case, that could be just one line with a single `if` condition that you think shouldn't return True but does do so in fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Detail of the problem:**

The **and** operator works on boolean values only.  It does *not* distribute over the **in** operator (remember the distributive law of multiplication over addition?).  Your expression

```
1 and 2 and 3 in win_list1
```

becomes

```
bool(1) and bool(2) and bool (3 in win_list1)
```

bool(n) is **False** for n=0, **True** for everything else.

---

**Immediate fix:**

Alex Hall already gave you that

**Better fix (perhaps):**

Renumber your array of choices to be a magic square:

```
6 7 2
1 5 9
8 3 4
```

Now, all you have to do is check whether you have a sum of 15 for any combination of three chosen positions.  You can generate all of those with

```
itertools.combinations(win_list1, 3)
```

This would reduce your checking from 18 lines to 1 (or 2-4, if you prefer that readability).

---

**Extra issue:**

Your logic on **bud** is a little weird.  I do understand the odd/even checking on the turn number:

```
if bud % 2 == 0:
```

However, the second one,

```
elif bud % 1 == 0:
```

is **True** for *any* integer.  The percent sign is the modulus operator: divide by the mod and keep the remainder.  In short, the second one is always true.  Just make it an **else**.

**Another ...**

Why not make **win_list** a 2-D list?  Use win_list[0] and win_list[1], so you can fold their code together.  You can simply have

```
player = bud % 2
win_list[player].append(position_list[bud])
if any(sum(itertools.combinations(win_list[player], 3)) == 15):
    ...
```

Comment: Wow that answer was really helpful, thanks. I had noticed the bud%1 error prior to reading it, but the stuff on the magic square and how boolean values worked was quite useful.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  This is why SO exists -- support each other.  The magic square trick is one I picked up in college, back in my FORTRAN !V and BASIC days.

Answer (score 1):

```
if 1 and 5 and 9 in win_list2:
```

should be:

```
if 1 in win_list2 and 5 in win_list2 and 9 in win_list2:
```

Answer (score 0):

In python

```
>> 1 and 2 and 3 in win_list1
```

is evaluated as

```
>> 3 in win_list1
```

which is True

Comment: More sepcifically, it's evaluated as bool(1) and bool(2) and bool (3 in win_list1). Since the first two are **True**, this reduces to the third value.